# how to use wcf in php?

Tags: c#, php, wcf, wsdl

I want to connect to this webservice but doesn't worked in php. Also, I used that in C# and it worked.

```
ServiceReference1.BillStateServiceClient bdclinet = new ServiceReference1.BillStateServiceClient();
s = bdclinet.VerifyBillPaymentWithAddData("4525226405917", "61860176", "10400061", "976258914");
```

And in php:

```
$soapclient = new nusoap_client("https://acquirer.samanepay.com/payments/referencepayment.asmx?WSDL", "wsdl");
$soapProxy = $soapclient->getProxy();
$res = $soapProxy>VerifyBillPaymentWithAddData("4525226405917", "61860176", "10400061", "976258914");
```

What's the problem?

Comment: what error do you get? doesn't work is too much to understand

Comment: get nothing , nothing recived

Comment: Show us exactly what you do (or don't) get, even if it's an empty object.

Comment: i want to get data from webservice in c# its ok but in php return null.